# Ensure last page is even and blank

Tags: blank-page, double-sided

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How I can automatically add a page if the total number of pages is odd?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56700/how-i-can-automatically-add-a-page-if-the-total-number-of-pages-is-odd)

I am writing a report in two-sided mode. Report is based on the `erdc`class file (with modifications), so I don't want to change that if possible. (The class file is probably not relevant but it is based on the standard `article` class, not `memoir`or `KOMA`).

I wish to ensure that the last even page is blank (not an issue if last page is odd as two-sided printing prints nothing on the reverse side and similarly in single sided mode...) Simple reason for this is that when stapled/bound no information is showing on the back page!

I know a very easy solution is just to add physically a blank page to the report before stapling/binding, but can this be implemented such that the output does contain this blank page