# Forcing even number of pages in output (LaTeX --- pdflatex)

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided, lastpage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep the last page number even?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38218/how-to-keep-the-last-page-number-even)

Is there a way of forcing an even number of pages in output ?

What I mean is to make pdflatex document "intelligent" it will add or not, blank page on the end to ensure there is always produced even number of pages.

(Purpose: I produce many of such pdfs and later combine them with external tool together in order to produce on pdf for double-side printing)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Issue `\clearpage` at the end of the document; then check whether the page number is odd and do nothing in this case, otherwise eject an empty page; the following code in the document preamble will do:

```
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\ifodd\value{page}\else\null\clearpage\fi}
```

This works independently of the `oneside` or `twoside` option. In the latter case

```
\AtEndDocument{\cleardoublepage}
```

is sufficient (as stated by Ulrike).

Comment: Isn't testing for `\value{page}` unreliable, as shown in the MWE to the linked question?

Comment: @lockstep If the test is put just after `\clearpage` it gives the correct result, because the output routine has just been performed.

Comment: Note: add a `\pagestyle{empty}` after the `\clearpage` to suppress the final page number.

Answer (score 3):

This here gives two pages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
abc
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it `book` class specific or general solution for any documentclass?

Comment: It works for any document class.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Raphink suggests `\cleardoublepage` adds page always. I need to add page only when is it needed. What do you think about it ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki No, `\cleardoublepage` works like you want only if `twoside` mode is active. With `oneside` (default e.g. in report or article) `\cleardoublepage` calls only `\clearpage`. But you can easily define your `alwayscleardoublepage` without this restriction. The original definition is in `latex.ltx`.

Comment: That's right. My code is only necessary because I'm using the `article` class instead of the `book` class.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you provide please an one more example showing how to make it working with `article` documentclass? I believe it will useful for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the cleanest way, and probably someone will come with something better:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}
{\cleardoublepage\mbox{}}
{}

\end{document}
```

Add/remove `\lipsum` to see how the number of pages evolves. The document will always have an even number of pages.

Invert `{}` and `{\cleardoublepage\mbox{}}` to ensure an odd number of pages.

Comment: What's the advantage above using only `\cleardoublepage` ?

Comment: It's dynamic. Using `\cleardoublepage` will add a new page, whether the number of pages is even or not. This code only adds a new page if the number of pages is odd, ensuring an even number of pages.

Comment: @Raphink No, `\cleardoublepage` will not add always a new page. It contains the same test you are doing (and it contains a `\clearpage` *before* the test to avoid problems with the asynchronous page which your code is missing.)

Comment: @Raphink I would love to see your solution improved by Ulrike suggestions, as It's much more flexible to standard `\cleardoublepage`. On the other hand, you might like to show how to use it for setting up "this page is intentionally blank" : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69115/this-page-was-left-intionally-blank-on-center-of-page

Comment: The clean way of doing it is @egreg's (not surprisingly).