# "This page was left intionally blank" on center of page

Tags: double-sided, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make pages which were “intentionally left blank”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-do-i-make-pages-which-were-intentionally-left-blank)

Assuming I am forcing amount of pages to be even using [Raphink's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/951/raphink) solution : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69112/7128

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\lipsum

\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}
{\cleardoublepage\mbox{}}
{}

\end{document}
```

How to put a nice grey large text in the center of page "This page was left intentionally blank" ?

I suppose it's the place where is `\mbox{}`, but how to typeset such information ?

(I use pdflatex)

Comment: slightly different, because I ask for solution where user decides when he wants to put "Intentionally Blank" information, but for sure worth to mention as closely related.

Comment: OK; there's at least one solution there that is 'the user's decision'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [@egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69118/951) is better, I'll use this one:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtEndDocument{\clearpage%
\ifodd\value{page}\else%
\newpage%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\large This page is intentionally left blank.}
\end{center}
\vfill
\fi}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use `\vspace*{\fill}` instead of `\mbox{}\vfill` (removing the final `\mbox{}`).