# Writing something on all blank pages in memoir

Tags: memoir, parts, blank-page

This question: [How do I write “This page intentionally left blank.” in memoir with custom chapter styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269611/how-do-i-write-this-page-intentionally-left-blank-in-memoir-with-custom-chapt)
tried for an answer to the question of how to write something on blank pages, but it does not write anything on blank pages around the `\part{partname}` command

an answer in the question was to use

```
\cleartooddpage[\vspace*{\fill}\centering BLANK PAGE \vspace*{\fill}]
```

but that must be called for every blank page, I'd like all blank pages to get the text.

```
\documentclass[openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\cleartoevenpage[\vspace*{\fill}\centering BLANK PAGE \vspace*{\fill}]
\makeatletter \def\clearforchapter{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else \hbox{}\vfill\begin{center}This page intentionally left blank.\end{center}\vfill \thispagestyle{cleared}%
\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}\makeatother


\begin{document}
Text before a part
\part{bob}
\chapter{the}
\chapter{cool}
\chapter{duck}
\end{document}
```

Has many blank pages, but not all are marked with text

Comment: Add a small complete example that can be used for tests. I e.g. have neither the will nor the time to assemble one from various snippets in older questions/answers.

Comment: See the definitions for `\cleartorecto`, `\cleartoverso` , they both use the cleared page style. BTW: why do people want to add `this page left intentionally blank`? I've never understood that.

Comment: @daleif To show that it wasn't left blank by mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be three (four) macros at play here (judging from your example code).

First, `\cleardoublepage`, which is the standard LaTeX command for clearing pages in two-sided documents. It is used before the `\part` in your document.

Second (and third), `\clearforchapter`, which is `memoir`'s command for using the correct page for a chapter heading. However this macro is defined to be either `\cleartorecto`, `\clearpage`, or `\cleartoverso` if any of `openright`, `openany`, or `openleft` was used, respectively (the default is `openright`). A *less wrong* change would be to add the intentionally-empty page text in these macros, so if you happen to change the `open...` option, your document won't be messed up. The answer you linked to *happen* to work because OP didn't use any option, so `openright` was used by default (and the redifinition was done based on `\cleartorecto`).

Fourth, `\partpageend`, which is used by `memoir` *after* a `\part`.

I also added, for convenience, a `\clearpagetext` command which shows from which of these macros it was called, just for bookkeeping. You can (and should :-) remove that from your document. That said, here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass[openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter

\def\clearpagetext#1{%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}%
    This page was intentionally left blank by \texttt{\string#1}.
  \end{center}%
  \vfill}

\if@openleft
  \def\cleartoverso{\clearpage\if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page\hbox{}%
    \clearpagetext\cleartoverso% <--
    \thispagestyle{cleared}%
    \newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\else
  \if@openright
    \def\cleartorecto{\clearpage\if@twoside
      \ifodd\c@page\else\hbox{}%
      \clearpagetext\cleartorecto% <--
      \thispagestyle{cleared}%
      \newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
  \fi
\fi

\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside
  \ifodd\c@page\else\hbox{}%
  \clearpagetext\cleardoublepage% <--
  \thispagestyle{cleared}%
  \newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}% (Yes, this is the same as \cleartoverso)

\def\partpageend{\afterpartskip
  \ifm@mnopartnewpage
  \else
    \if@twoside
      \if@openright
        \null
        \clearpagetext\partpageend% <--
        \thispagestyle{afterpart}%
        \newpage
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text before a part
\part{bob}
\chapter{the}
\chapter{cool}
\chapter{duck}
\end{document}
```

The document structure will look like this (behold my fabulous ASCII art):

```
|---------------|   |---------------|
| Text before   |   | This page was |
| a part        |   | intentionally |
|               | → | left blank by |
|       1       |   | \cleardoublepage. |% <-- Overfull \hbox
|---------------| ↙ |---------------|
|---------------|   |---------------|
|     Part I    |   | This page was |
|      Bob      |   | intentionally |
|               |   | left blank by |
|       3       |   | \partpageend. |
|---------------|   |---------------|
|---------------|   |---------------|
| Chapter 1     |   | This page was |
| the           |   | intentionally |
|               |   | left blank by |
|       5       |   | \cleartorecto |
|---------------|   |---------------|
|---------------|   |---------------|
| Chapter 2     |   | This page was |
| cool          |   | intentionally |
|               |   | left blank by |
|       7       |   | \cleartorecto |
|---------------|   |---------------|
|---------------|
| Chapter 3     |
| duck          |
|               |
|       9       |
|---------------|
```