# How I can automatically add a page if the total number of pages is odd?

Tags: header-footer, conditionals, double-sided, blank-page

I need automatically add a blank page (also **without document header, numbering and footer**) at the end of the document, if the total numbers of pages is odd. How I can do that?
And preferably without using any additional package. :)

Comment: Maybe the answer by Martin Scharrer to my question [Ensure last page is even and blank](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19687) may also be of help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\begin{document}

one
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

Or you could use this version

```
\makeatletter

\def\emptycleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

\makeatother
```

which is the same as the standard `\cleardoublepage` except for the `\thispagestyle{empty}%` of course you don't just have to use `empty` you can have page style that inserts `this page intentionally blank` or whatever else is needed.

Comment: Damn! I've already reached the vote limit, but in 58min. I will upvote this as many times as I can ;-)

Comment: Thanks! @DavidCarlisle. It's a very good solution. Adding `\cleardoublepage` it works , but in the last page appears the headers, the numbering and document footer. How I can remove it? Maybe It's just a simple command! :D

Comment: there's probably a qn on site somewhere that has a modified cleardoublepage with a modified page style, but I'll add it to the qn (it's generally useful not just for last page)

Comment: Ok, Thanks!. The solution of @GonzaloMedina Works perfectly, but I wish it did not require the use of other packages.

Comment: Thanks! @DavidCarlisle Works perfectly as I needed. Thanks! again.

Comment: Voted, as promised, as many times as I could!

Comment: The `emptypage` package will blank all pages added by a `\cleardoublepage` command.

Answer (score 15):

Original answer to [Ensure last page is even and blank](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19687/2975) (now merged with this question.)

---

If you want to ensure even number of pages in `twoside` mode you can simply add `\cleardoublepage` at the end of the document, either manually or using `\AtEndDocument{..}`. If you want to have the page blank you need to modify the code used by `\cleardoublepage` slightly to include a `\thispagestyle`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

%\AtEndDocument{\cleardoublepage}
\AtEndDocument{% based in \cleardoublepage
  \clearpage
  \ifodd\value{page}\else
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \hbox{}\newpage
  \fi
}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-47]

\end{document}
```

This is for `twoside` document only. See my answer to [How to force output to a left (or right) page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/how-to-force-output-to-a-left-or-right-page/11709#11709) for the extra code needed to behave well in `oneside` documents as well.

Comment: Martin's [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/how-to-force-output-to-a-left-or-right-page/11709#11709) works a treat and has been implemented into the class file,  Cheers, leeser

Comment: @JosephWright sorry to be pedantic but why was my original question of a year ago "closed as exact duplicate" of this later question? Surely it should be the other way around?

Comment: @Lesser From time to time it makes sense to 'reverse dupe' or 'reverse merge' a question. In this case, the dupe only really got flagged up up after answers had been posted to the newer one, and the way voting had worked out it made more sense to 'keep' the newer question. That's not a judgement on your question at all: it's about trying to make the most of the overall amount of information on the site.

Comment: @JosephWright Ok I understand that and see the logic, but can I get my 2 points reputation back! (-2 rep due to merge) I'm languishing on low numbers so 2 points is about 0.5% to me!!!!

Answer (score 14):

Here's one possible option: with the help of the `lastpage` package, you can check if the last page is odd or even; in the first case, add an extra page with `empty` style; otherwise, do nothing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{LastPage}}}{\null\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}}{}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Actually, a refinement is needed to satisfy the condition for the added page (`empty` page style):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\makeatletter
\def\emptyclearpage{%
  \ifvmode
    \ifnum \@dbltopnum =\m@ne
      \ifdim \pagetotal <\topskip
        \hbox{}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
  \write\m@ne{}%
  \vbox{}%
  \penalty -\@Mi
}
\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{%
  \emptyclearpage
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{LastPage}}}{\null\emptyclearpage}{}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! @GonzaloMedina. You know any way to do this without additional packages?

Comment: @osjerick see David's answer!

Comment: @osjerick I've updated my previous answer with new code needed to satisfy the requirement of no footer/header on the added page. David's solution as it is now doen't fulfill this requirement.

Comment: Thanks! @GonzaloMedina. I run the last MWE, but this doesn't add the blank page!

Comment: @osjerick you need to process the document at least twice.

Comment: I see it now! Thanks!. The idea of not using other packages for this is for possible use of the solution in the code of a new document class, avoiding the use of `RequirePackage`.

Comment: @osjerick I can easily avoid using `ifthen`, but since my code requires the use the value of the page counter for the last page, I don't see at the moment an easy way to dispense with the use of `lastpage`, but I'll think about it. David's answer, on the other hand, can be easily corrected to deal with the headers/footers issue.

Comment: Ok, Thanks again @GonzaloMedina! Gracias! :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\AtEndDocument` to add an empty page to the end of the document if the text ends on an even page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\AtEndDocument{ \ifodd\value{page}\else\newpage\thispagestyle{empty} \hbox{} \fi }
\begin{document}
A \newpage B \newpage C \newpage D
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the page number is reset at an even page number (e.g. page 50 becomes new page 1), which might happen if different numbering schemes (e.g. Roman for the frontmatter) are used, or when \addtocounter{page}{...}, \setcounter or some other "nastiness" is used, a page with an even number might be on the right instead left side (or verso instead of recto). (Probably not very common, but probability is still larger zero.)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [`emptypage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/emptypage) package on a `twoside` document, you can have the last page even and blank using this:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\cleardoublepage}

\begin{document}
A \newpage B % \newpage C
\end{document}
```