# How to ensure document total page numbers is a multiple of four?

Tags: page-breaking, conditionals, calculations

I'm producing a document (book class) that will ultimately be produced using offset lithography. It's therefore useful to ensure the total number of pages is a multiple of four by adding as many blank pages to the end as is appropriate.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56700/how-i-can-automatically-add-a-page-if-the-total-number-of-pages-is-odd) deals with adding a page if necessary to make the total number even. I can't figure out how to adapt it to deal with multiples of four. Is there a way?

Comment: Are you sure you will need it? Aren't such systems able to add blank pages during the printing process?

Comment: That's a fair comment Ulrike and yes, 'need' would be too strong a word. It just seemed like a handy thing to be able to automate at the production side so I wanted to give it a shot.

Comment: on production side are no single pages printed ...

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630150/43807 which deals with forcing a back cover as multiple of 4, absolute PDF page numbers (for when the usual counter is reset somewhere in the document), and forcing an extra blank page (for the inner back cover)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\numexpr` divisions round, so they are not so good in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount,lastpage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\checkmultipleoffour}{%
  \count@=\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}%
  \@tempcnta=\count@
  \divide\@tempcnta by 4
  \multiply\@tempcnta by 4
  \count@=\numexpr\count@-\@tempcnta\relax
  \ifnum\count@>0
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \loop\ifnum\count@<4
      \null\clearpage
      \advance\count@\@ne
    \repeat
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{\checkmultipleoffour}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-11] % for a 4 page document

% \kant[1-15] % for a 5 page document

\end{document}
```

The same in `expl3` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{refcount,lastpage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkmultipleoffour} { }
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn
   { \int_mod:nn { 4 - \int_mod:nn { \getpagerefnumber{LastPage} } { 4 } } { 4 } }
   { \thispagestyle{empty}\null\clearpage }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AtEndDocument{\checkmultipleoffour}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-11] % for a 4 page document

% \kant[1-15] % for a 5 page document

\end{document}
```

---

With `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` the situation is a bit more complicated.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{refcount,lastpage,etoolbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\mainmatter{\cleardoublepage}
  {%
   \clearpage\edef\@currentlabel{\number\numexpr\arabic{page}\ifodd\arabic{page}+1\fi\relax}%
   \label{LastFrontmatterPage}%
   \cleardoublepage
  }{}{}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \egreg_int_coremainder:nn #1 #2
 {
  \int_mod:nn { #2 - \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkmultipleoffour} { O{0} }
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn
   {
    \egreg_int_coremainder:nn { #1 + \getrefnumber{LastFrontmatterPage} + \getpagerefnumber{LastPage} } { 4 }
   }
   { \thispagestyle{empty}\null\clearpage }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AtEndDocument{\checkmultipleoffour}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{A}

\kant[1-11]

\end{document}
```

The `\checkmultipleoffour` has also an optional argument where specifying possible pages *before* `\frontmatter` (an unnumbered frontispiece, for instance).

Note that a couple of LaTeX runs may be needed, because these macros require the `\label`-`\ref` system to synchronize.

Comment: Won't this also suffer from the `\frontmatter`...`\backmatter` problem?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing it on my document - I'm getting 58 pages. Is it possible for a package to conflict with something like this?

Comment: @StephanLehmke Yes, I've added a version for this.

Comment: @cms_mgr My tests give correct results, I don't know what to say. However two (or more) runs are necessary for the process to stabilize.

Comment: Comment was before the updated version, going to try it now.

Comment: Working now, thanks for your time and effort on this.

Answer (score 6):

I realise that the goal of this is probably to implement a TeX solution, but it really, really is easier after the document has been completed.

```
file=UITutorial.pdf; pdftk A=$file B=blank.pdf cat A1-end $(repeat $(( (4-(${$(pdfinfo $file| grep '^Pages:'):s/Pages://:s/ /})%4)%4 )) print -n "B1 ") output ${file:r}_4pgs.pdf
```

or if you prefer it spaced out a bit:

```
file=UITutorial.pdf; \
pdftk A=$file B=blank.pdf \
cat A1-end \
$(repeat $(( (4-(${$(pdfinfo $file| grep '^Pages:'):s/Pages://:s/ /})%4)%4 )) print -n "B1 ")\
output ${file:r}_4pgs.pdf
```

Works with `zsh` on Unix (Linux, MacOSX, ...), don't know if it would work with other shells.  Needs `blank.pdf` to be a PDF consisting of a single blank page.

Explanation:

```
file=UITutorial.pdf; \
```

sets the file we'll use so that we only have to refer to it once

```
pdftk A=$file B=blank.pdf \
```

Our inputs will be our given file and the blank PDF.

```
cat A1-end \
```

The `cat` command says "Concatenate the following pages into our output" and the first set of pages are all of those from the main file.

```
$(repeat $(( (4-(${$(pdfinfo $file| grep '^Pages:'):s/Pages://:s/ /})%4)%4 )) print -n "B1 ")\
```

The second set is a bit more complicated.  We find out how many pages our PDF has via the `pdfinfo` command.  Then we take this modulo 4.  We want to round up to the nearest multiple of 4 so we want to take `4 - <this number>` except that if `<this number>` is already a multiple of 4 we don't want to add any.  So we work out `(4 - <pages>%4)%4`.  Then we insert into the page specification `B1` that number of times.  This says "Take page 1 from source B" (which was the blank one) and we do it the right number of times.

```
output ${file:r}_4pgs.pdf
```

Now we direct our output to `<filename>_4pgs.pdf`, where `<filename>` is what we originally specified but with the extension stripped off.

Answer (score 5):

Hijacking Davids code, try

```
\makeatletter
\def\emptyclearquadpage
{%
  \clearpage
  \@emptyclearquadpage
}
\def\@emptyclearquadpage
{%
  \ifnum\numexpr((\c@page+1)/4-1)*4+1\relax=\c@page
   \else
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi
    \expandafter
    \@emptyclearquadpage
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

This will basically produce empty pages to fill up the page counter to a multiple of 4. Adjust as needed.

Sorry for the clumsy numexpr, the totally irrational rounding of integer division is driving me mad...

### Edit

Thanks to Ulrike for pointing out that `\pagenumbering` resets the page counter, so it's not safe to count on it ;-)

Fascinating that `\cleardoublepage` also only works by coincidence and well-behaving document classes then...

Try

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\def\emptyclearquadpage
{%
  \clearpage
  \@emptyclearquadpage
}
\def\@emptyclearquadpage
{%
  \@tempcnta=\numexpr\c@page+\totalpages-\@ne\relax
  \ifnum\numexpr((\@tempcnta+2)/4-1)*4\relax=\@tempcnta
   \else
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi
    \expandafter
    \@emptyclearquadpage
  \fi
}

\newcount\totalpages

\pretocmd{\pagenumbering}
{\global\advance\totalpages\numexpr\c@page-\@ne\relax}{}{}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\clearpage foo
\clearpage foo

\mainmatter

\clearpage foo
\clearpage foo
\clearpage foo


\emptyclearquadpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: It will only work if you don't change the numbering system in the book. With e.g. `\fontmatter abc \mainmatter abc` I get 6 pages.

Comment: Yes I have to confirm this one isn't doing the trick I'm afraid.

Comment: Wow, to consider there is indeed no counter giving the total number of pages in a LaTeX document ;-)  ... see my edit.