# Printing absolute page numbers

Tags: page-numbering, counters

I'm using the [`pagesel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pagesel) package to output only selected parts of a large document. The page numbers in that document are not absolute page numbers, but pagesel (quite rightly) uses absolute page numbers. So what I'd like to do is, within my document, put a command to list the absolute page number on my TeX log. The `pagesel` package uses the counter `ps@count` to keep track of the absolute page number, so I've tried the following two ideas, but neither works:

```
\makeatletter 
\typeout{Absolute Page \value{ps@count}} 
\makeatother

\makeatletter 
\typeout{Absolute Page \theps@count} 
\makeatother
```

Could someone fix one of these? (I see from another answer [How to find absolute page number as an integer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24236/how-to-find-absolute-page-number-as-an-integer) that I could use the [`zref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zref) package, but that seems a lot of work when pagesel already has the counter that I want.)

Comment: to everyone stumbling upon this, see also https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60142085#60142085 and following for if you need an absolute page number but cannot use `pagesel` (it breaks the build with undefined references for me), for example for [inserting blank pages to align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130130/43807) e.g. for a back cover

Answer (score 3):

If you load the [`pagesel` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pagesel) without specifying any selection options (that's the main purpose of the package), then it virtually "unloads" itself. From the [`pagesel` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pagesel.pdf) (section **1 Usage**, p 2):

> Depending on the options the package works in two modes:
>
> 1. If no page selecting option is present, so the package ignores the other options
>      and finishes itself. So no page will be suppressed by the package and auxiliary
>      files will be written.
> 2. With at least one page selecting option the specified pages are selected and
>      the other are suppressed. The default for this mode is that auxiliary will
>      not be overwritten. (This can be changed by an option.)

You can load `pagesel` and specify that all pages should be written out using the `-` option as a page range. Just as an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[-]{pagesel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pagesel
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
\EveryShipout{\typeout{Absolute page \theps@count.}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

will output in your `.log` (somewhere):

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
Absolute page 1.
[1

{c:/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Absolute page 2.
[2] )
```

Note that `pagesel` uses [`everyshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi) to determine the page count at shipout time. That is the only reliable time that you can use the page counter, so you should too.