# Back page in booklet

Tags: memoir, book-design

I'm writing a booklet and I'm facing a problem with the back page. Printing the resulting `PDF` of the `LaTeX` project as a booklet often result in a unwanted layout. I mean... to have the back cover in the last booklet page the total number of pages in the *book* should be divisble by 4.
Up to now I'm solving this placing *blank* pages to match the correct number, I would like to avoid this in a more *programmatic* way or using some features of `LaTeX` itself.
Up to now I'm using this document class:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,a5paper,twoside,openright,italian,12pt]{memoir}
```

I'm printing this on A4 paper and folding.

The backpage is defined through this command:

```
\newcommand{\myback}{%
    \cleartoleftpage%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{center}%
        \begin{vplace}[0.7]%
            \def\svgwidth{60mm}%
            \input{logo_red.pdf_tex}%
            %\includegraphics[width = 60mm]{logo_red.png}%
        \end{vplace}
        \vfill%
        {\color{red} \huge \textcopyright~\thedate}%
    \end{center}
}
```

and refers to another custom command:

```
\newcommand*\cleartoleftpage{%
    \clearpage
    \ifodd\value{page}\hbox{}\newpage\fi
}
```

that works fine on books since it forces backpage to be on an *even* page.

How can I modify such condition to fit my current needs?

BTW I'm not using the `booklet` package (but as long as I can see there are not specific functions to create a back cover in the last page).

Comment: found an answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130130/how-to-insert-a-blank-page-depending-on-current-page-number

Comment: if you're happy with that answer, perhaps this can be closed as a duplicate.  on the other hand, that question uses the `article` document class, and your booklet is based on `memoir`.  if there are particular things you need to pay attention to, you could show them with a self-answer, which might save someone else from recreating the specifics.

Comment: The last part of my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323433/how-to-make-a-a4-sheet-made-of-a7-pages/323436#323436 also provides a way to add blank pages programmatically. The method is similar to the one in the linked question, but uses `expl3`.