# Ensure document pages are multiple of 16

Tags: page-numbering

I need to produce a series of book and the typography asked me to provide documents with the total number of pages multiple of 16.
I tried to follow this answer [How to ensure document total page numbers is a multiple of four?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83488/how-to-ensure-document-total-page-numbers-is-a-multiple-of-four), using the example working with `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, but I am not able to modify it to output multiple of 16. Any advice?

EDIT: for convenience, full code below:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{refcount,lastpage,etoolbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\mainmatter{\cleardoublepage}
  {%
   \clearpage\edef\@currentlabel{\number\numexpr\arabic{page}\ifodd\arabic{page}+1\fi\relax}%
   \label{LastFrontmatterPage}%
   \cleardoublepage
  }{}{}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \egreg_int_coremainder:nn #1 #2
 {
  \int_mod:nn { #2 - \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkmultipleoffour} { O{0} }
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn
   {
    \egreg_int_coremainder:nn { #1 + \getrefnumber{LastFrontmatterPage} + \getpagerefnumber{LastPage} } { 4 }
   }
   { \thispagestyle{empty}\null\clearpage }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AtEndDocument{\checkmultipleoffour}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Wouldn't it be for an *in-octavo* printing?

Comment: Thank you, Bernard! Yes, I did not know the right word in english, sorry!

Comment: Using the cited answer, and changing the three instances of `4` to `16` seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it works. But if you have a document with frontmatter and mainmatter, for what I understand, you have to use the last example, which I am not able to modify to work with 16.

Comment: OK, but when I use egreg's last example, changing the one instance of `4` to `16`, it also seems to work.

Comment: If I change 4 into 16, I get what's required. Note that you need *two* LaTeX runs for the `\label`-`\ref` system to get synchronized. I added a note.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for help. Using the minimal working example it works perfectly but, it's strange, on my document I am not able to make it work..

Comment: SOLVED! It was, of course, my mistake. I positioned \frontmatter after the title page and the toc, so the calculations made were not correct.