# Package that fills pages to total number of pages devideable by 4, 8, 16

Tags: macros, book-design

I'm doing a package right now, which is capable of filling in empty or custom pages to get a total number of pages which is devideable by a defined number.

I just want to make sure, that a package like this doesn't exist already.

It is not yet, but can be extended by the option "divideable by x plus y". i.e. 18. 16 is devideable by 4 plus 2.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83488/how-to-ensure-document-total-page-numbers-is-a-multiple-of-four

Comment: @egreg As far as I see, there isn't a package like this. My package should be able to insert blank pages at defined points with pre defined content. i.e. a picture or "this is a blank page on purpose" In other words: I can continue working without worrying that I might do work, that already has been done by someone.

Comment: No, I don't think there is such a package