# A template for documentation for ctan

Tags: package-writing, documentation

I got my Fill-Pages-Package (hopefully bug free) ready, which is my first package. Now I want to upload it on ctan. But first there must be a documentation. I've been searching for a template for the documentation of the package, but haven't found anything yet.

Does anybody here have a useful template or a source for it?

Note: The package is an advanced solution for [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305316/package-that-fills-pages-to-total-number-of-pages-devideable-by-4-8-16).

Comment: `ltxdoc` class perhaps. I use `tcolorbox` and `tcbdocumentation` library for my personal stuff.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B Fill-Pages-Package or the template?

Comment: The question is unanswered for a while, as it stands it is very very broad.