# How to place INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK in the middle of the page while using two columns throughout the document?

Tags: two-column, blank-page

From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56700/how-i-can-automatically-add-a-page-if-the-total-number-of-pages-is-odd) I used the following codes to add an empty INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK page if a section ended in an odd number of pages, as well as if the total document would end in an odd number of pages (because for some reason it doesn't add the blankpage to the last section)

```
\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
%\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}%
   % \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
\vspace*{\fill}
{ \centering INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK.\par}
\vspace{\fill}}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\blankpage
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{%

 \ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{LastPage}}}{\null\blankpage}{}}
```

Now here's my own question: the code made by the famous @DavidCarlisle seems to hint that if a two column setup is used, it would still place the "INTENT...BLANK" part right in the middle of the page. And it did! And then suddenly, it stopped doing it and started placing it on the left side of the page which I would guess to be centered in the left column. So how can I overrule the two columns and still have the sentence placed in the middle? The last page seems to be doing it right even though the \end{multicols} is *after* that last section.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Rather than posting code fragments, it is easier to help you if you post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a KOMA-Script class, you can use:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\usepackage{mwe}

\DeclareNewLayer[%
  background,
  align=c,
  area={.5\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}{0pt}{0pt},
  contents={\makebox[0pt][c]{INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK.}}
]{ilb}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{ilb}{ilb}
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=ilb}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Test Chapter}
This short chapter will result in an empty next page.

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

For the standard classes, you need also package `scrextend`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\usepackage{mwe}

\DeclareNewLayer[%
  background,
  align=c,
  area={.5\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}{0pt}{0pt},
  contents={\makebox[0pt][c]{INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK.}}
]{ilb}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{ilb}{ilb}
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=ilb}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Test Chapter}
This short chapter will result in an empty next page.

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

To make the last page an empty even page, you can simply add

```
\AtEndDocument{\ifodd\value{page}\cleardoublepage\fi}
```

to the document preamble.

It also works if you do not use `twocolumn` option but package `multicols`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{multicol}

\DeclareNewLayer[%
  background,
  align=c,
  area={.5\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}{0pt}{0pt},
  contents={\makebox[0pt][c]{INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK.}}
]{ilb}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{ilb}{ilb}
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=ilb}

\AtEndDocument{\ifodd\value{page}\cleardoublepage\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\chapter{First Test Chapter}
This short chapter will result in an empty next page.

\blinddocument

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```